CloudFront function association - Invalid request provided: The function ARN must reference a specific function version
I've created an AWS::CloudFront::Function using CloudFormation (template here). Then I've tried to associate with a distribution following the LambdaFunctionAssociation docs:
DistributionConfig:
  DefaultCacheBehavior:
    LambdaFunctionAssociations:
      EventType: viewer-request
      LambdaFunctionARN: !GetAtt Function_Logical_ID.FunctionMetadata.FunctionARN

And I get the following error: Invalid request provided: The function ARN must reference a specific function version. (The ARN must end with the version number.)
How to associate a CloudFront Function using CloudFormation?

My mistake was that I was using LambdaFunctionAssociations instead of FunctionAssociations (docs here):


FunctionAssociations are for CloudFront functions;
LambdaFunctionAssociations are for Lambda@Edge.

Then I changed to the template below and it worked:
DistributionConfig:
  DefaultCacheBehavior:
    FunctionAssociations:
      EventType: viewer-request
      FunctionARN: !GetAtt Function_Logical_ID.FunctionMetadata.FunctionARN

